# How to align rules like this?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

I need align this rules but I can't. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: @AlejandroBenitez please see if the answer meets the requirement -- the length of the rule and thickness can be controlled with the options `\rule{length}{thickness}` and the `tabto` package ensures tabbing environment

Comment: @AlejandroBenitez the second option uses `makebox` with the same result

Comment: oops sorry its @AlejandraBenitez

Comment: Problem solved? If yes, then please consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \NumTabs{4}
\item text \tab{\rule{6cm}{0.15mm}}
\item text text \tab{\rule{6cm}{0.15mm}}
\item text text text \tab{\rule{6cm}{0.15mm}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**another option with makebox**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]

\item \makebox[3cm][l]{It would be nice} \makebox[2cm][l]{\rule{2cm}{0.3mm}}
\item \makebox[3cm][l]{It would} \makebox[2cm][l]{\rule{2cm}{0.3mm}}
\item \makebox[3cm][l]{It } \makebox[2cm][l]{\rule{2cm}{0.3mm}}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second makebox is overkill.